# Can't login into my admin account [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I can't login into my admin account. And I can't figure it out why? Because it don't show any error and that is why i can't figure it out what is happening. How can I fix this error? I'm trying to create a multi authentication. So I create another authentication for my admin account. When I tried to submit the details such as email and password then i click the submit button. It refreshing the login page again with email address being putted inside the email form and blank password. It don't show any error.

This is how it looks after I'm clicking the submit button.

```
  // login route
    Route::get('/login',[AdminLoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login',[AdminLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login.submit');
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate form data
        $this->validate($request,
            [
                'email' => 'required|string|email',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:8'
            ]
        );

        // Attempt to login as admin
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
            // If successful then redirect to intended route or admin dashboard
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }

        // If unsuccessful then redirect back to login page with email and remember fields
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftyhl.png
```

Comment: You wouldn't see any errors because there is nothing sending errors with the redirect ... is there a reason you are using 'multiauth'?

Comment: because I want to create 1 page for user and 1 page for admin that will have their own function

Comment: On Google Chrome if you inspect element -> network tab -> click "login" can you share if it gives you an error or what it says

Answer (score 0):

Your code here

```
// If unsuccessful then redirect back to login page with email and remember fields
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
```

Means it is returning the email and remember inputs. If you want an error, You need to set it
like (You can customise the message to your liking

```
        return redirect()->back()->with(['Input' => $request->only('email', 'remember'), 'error' => 'Your Email and Password do not match our records!']);
```

and then set where the session is flushed to the user in admin-login.blade file.